# Strange random-seed behaviour after create-<breeds>-with

Tags: netlogo

I am experiencing some strange random-seed behaviour in my model.

The following procedure:

```
to testRNG
  clear-all

  random-seed 10

  type random 100
  type ","

  create-nodes 10

  type random 100
  type ","

  ask nodes[ create-node2node-links-with other nodes in-radius (1000)]

  print random 100
end
```

Produces output that looks like this:

```
observer> testRNG
78,78,42
observer> testRNG
78,78,42
observer> testRNG
78,78,40
observer> testRNG
78,78,42
observer> testRNG
78,78,71
observer> testRNG
78,78,52
observer> testRNG
78,78,71
observer> testRNG
78,78,40
observer> testRNG
78,78,97
observer> testRNG
78,78,52
observer> testRNG
78,78,97
observer> testRNG
78,78,52
observer> testRNG
78,78,18
observer> testRNG
78,78,19
observer> testRNG
78,78,27
observer> testRNG
78,78,34
observer> testRNG
78,78,58
observer> testRNG
78,78,52
observer> testRNG
78,78,40
```

Obviously something is happening when the breeded links are created, but I am really unsure what it is. For completeness note that node2node-links are undirected and declared as:

```
undirected-link-breed [node2node-links node2node-link]
```

Puzzlingly, while the third call to random 100 is clearly not reproducible, it also looks like it may not be pseudo-random.

I have investigated this a little further and something strange is clearly happening - here is a another example from my actual runtime code. In this case the links are created after the 5th call to random 100, subsequent calls are not reproducible - however I have to think that the odds of the RNG generating "34, 1, 1" seven times out of nineteen would be very small.

```
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 10 , 67 , 2 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 1 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 60 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 29 , 32 , 41 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 16 , 71 , 78 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 10 , 67 , 2 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 1 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 1 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 1 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 1 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 29 , 32 , 41 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 81 , 26 , 63 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 92 , 11 , 93 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 88 , 93 , 60 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 1 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 1 , 1 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 34 , 93 , 60 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 88 , 93 , 60 END
START 66 , 62 , 61 , 21 , 62 , 94 , 11 , 38 END
```

I have created a blank model with just the node and node2node breeds/link-breeds and this single procedure and the behaviour does not occur - instead all calls to random 100 are reproducible.

I am at pains to include all my model code as it is fairly long and would undoubtedly be information overload - moreover, by calling clear-all I think I can rule out dependancy on some other section of the program.

If anyone has any ideas on what might be happening here, or can highlight something simple I have overlooked, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am wondering if the line `ask nodes[ create-node2node-links-with other nodes in-radius (1000)]` has a different number of operations each time in your real code. The code extract does not contain your node creation and presumably a different set of nodes (in different positions) are created each time you run the program. This means that the number of nodes within the radius for connection would be different each time. If the random-seed is set before node creation, do you still get the problem?

Comment: I had considered this but I am creating the nodes after the seed is set (see line 9: create-nodes 10). For now this is a real doozy - my guess is it will end up being something very simple but easily overlooked as you suggest. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Also, in my original code I set the seed in my setup function directly after a clear-all.

Comment: I get `78,78,76` every time I run your code in an otherwise blank model. What widgets do you have? I'm wondering if the code behind one of them (perhaps a monitor) is advancing the RNG. Monitors are updated sporadically, so it could be a timing thing with one of them. This would likely be considered a bug though (monitors and plots are supposed to use an auxiliary RNG).

Comment: I think I have isolated the problem...
I have a monitor displaying the number of graphs in the environment (which I always want to be 1) - it runs the following code:

`length nw:weak-component-clusters`

Once I remove this monitor runs become reproducible. I will need to do some more testing but this seems to fix the problem. I am unsure if this is a bug or simply not something I should be running in a monitor. Either way, many thanks Bryan.

Comment: This is absolutely a bug! Good catch! I've opened an issue in NW for it: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments:

This is due to a bug in the NW extension where running `nw:weak-component-clusters` in a monitor was sporadically advancing the main random number generator. Monitors and plots are meant to use their own RNG, so any code you run in a monitor or plot should not affect the outcome of other code.

https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/144

Comment: please see my comment at [link](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/144), this issue is still present in NetLogo 5.2 even with nw:distance-to